# What is a better solution for save client machine time on server?

Tags: time, client

I need to save client machine time when he log in on my web application. For this I have 2 solution

1. Using javascript
2. Store the server time

`System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();`

and ask the user in which timezone he is in

```
TimeZoneInfo indTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

What is the better solution to do this taks, using 1st one or 2nd one?
If there is any better solution then please give me.

Comment: I like the idea of a "batter" solution, but I think you meant "better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the client's time, you have to use javascript. All server-based solutions can't access the client's clock.

So, there is no better solution, sorry.

Comment: Dear Sven, some time javascript may be fail due to browser compatibility.

Comment: Well, more likely due to the user having disabled it. But if it fails, you could always store the server's time and use that.

Other possibility: Always store the server time and ask the user in which timezone he is in.

Comment: I think 2nd one is the better solution